# If $\gcd(a,bc)=d$, we can say that $d|a$ and $d|bc$ but what about $d|b$, $d|c$ individually?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I am learning about the proof of the theorem:
If $(b,c)=1$, then $(a,b)(a,c)=(a,bc)$. I have completed more than half of the theorem proof but at the end
I let $(a,bc)=d$, and i know that $d \mid a,d \mid bc$ can i write also $d \mid c$ and $d \mid b$ individually?. Because $bc$ is the product of two integers. Please clarify my confusion. Thank you.

Comment: Just try examples.  You should easily see that we need not have $d$ dividing either $b$ or $c$.

Comment: To get modern notation for divisibility in MathJax use the character `|` or `\mid`.

Comment: The text book i m using writing directly the that $d/d_1c$ for another integer $d_1$. I wanna know that how can he write $d/d_1c$ even we dont know about $d/c$.

Comment: Only if $d$ is a prime (or $1$) , we have $d\mid bc\implies d\mid b\ or\ d\mid c$

Comment: Your assertion is incorrect. You can try a stronger proof.

Comment: No you can't write until and unless d is prime or one. If d is not prime then consider following counterexample: Take d=6,b=2 and c=3. Then $d \mid ab$ that is $6|2×3$ but 6 doesn't divide 2 or 3.

Comment: Ok thank you for your replies i got the point.